# library for Java/Groovy code analysis

Tags: java, groovy, code-analysis

I have a project that should analyze Java and Groovy code and build a special script from the source code.

Googling code analysis libraries didn't really result in anything useful for me.
But someone gave me a link to the Spoon project to analyze Java code.

Right now, the only parts that I need from Spoon are to give a set of .java files and it will return me the source code in a big data structure provided by Spoon.
So far the code that I use:

```
private CtPackage analyzeSourceCode()
{
    Launcher spoon = new Launcher();
    this.javaFiles.forEach(spoon::addInputResource);
    spoon.buildModel();
    return spoon.getFactory().Package().getRootPackage();
}
```

After which, I build up whatever I need from the packages returned.
(Note that I also require the actual executions, not only the data structures and members of the source code.)

But this only works for .java files and not for .groovy files... which brings me back to the point where I need a library to analyze Groovy code.
This one also doesn't allow me to use Java and Groovy together, so I need something else anyway.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong in my google searches or provide me with links to a library that can analyze Java and Groovy code?